# How to avoid the session timeout in selenium grid

Tags: java

How to avoid the session timeout in selenium grid.

Some times the browser is closed automatically and could see the message as
"session deleted due to client timeout".Can you please reply how to set the timeout 
to great extend "999999".I used timeout parameter as =0 in hub config file.

Selenium:Webdriver
Browser:Firefox
Language:Java

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Config details :
hub launched with :-role hub -log /var/log/selenium_hub_log 
the final configuration comes from :
the default :
host : null
port : 4444
cleanupCycle : 5000
**timeout : 300000**
newSessionWaitTimeout : -1
grid1Mapping : {}
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
prioritizer : null
servlets :
```

Hope that help

Comment: Hi Ra'ad Bin,I configured like this 'java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -timeout=9999 -browserTimeout=9999 -role hub' or to -1 , now to extend for long time.Am i doing the right configuration? so far it is working as expected.1.Still needs to know whether it is correct or not 2.Is is possible to config through  code at triggering point